# Layout Issue while trying to hide toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

My current layout is

```
Toolbar

Tablayout

Webview
```

I am trying to hide the toolbar as the user scrolls up and show it again as the user scrolls down with the webview thats just below the tablayout. I am following the tutorials but in my case although I get the affect the Toolbar is not completely scrolled (i.e 1/3 is still in the view) more over I can't view the webview which I believe is to do with the layout implementation. Please correct the layout below

Appbarmain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here the relativelayout is too small hence I can't view the webview .This is **fragment.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/swipe1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/website_detail_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:numColumns="1"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is the Fragment that contains the webview called from the activity

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {



    // private String url;
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar1;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout1;

    public NewsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static NewsFragment newInstance(String webUrl) {
        //set arguments
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("website", webUrl);
        NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment();

        newsFragment.setArguments(args);

        return newsFragment;

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);


    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //get back arguments
        final String url = this.getArguments().getString("website");


        progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.website_detail_1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                progressBar1.setProgress(progress);

                if (progress == 100) {

                    progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout1.isRefreshing()) {
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                } else {
                    progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }


        });


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        });


        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        //   webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) { // loading offline
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        }


        webView.loadUrl(url);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout1 = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe1);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });

        webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: Show your activity code if possible. And you are trying to load webview in viewpager right?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to load a webview in view pager. Is activity necessary ? Activity just calls out to load fragment.xml (updated)

Comment: Ok let me just try.Wait for few mins.

Comment: Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your AppBarLayout!

Comment: @UttamPanchasara doesn't help.

Comment: try to remove from CoordinatorLayout and let it be only in AppBarLayout... ,
 
for more with CoordinatorLayout check this link you will surely get idea..  https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 1):

Add below line to your NestedScrollView :

```
 android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: Yes this does show the webview but the downside is now i can't scroll the view. I have updated the fragment that contains the webview if it could help

Comment: What is not scrolling?And what do you want to scroll?

Comment: when I use `android:fillVierport ="true"` as per your suggestion, Yes I can see the webview now but the webview that previously had the property to scroll is now disabled moreover swipe to refresh that I have implemented in the layout also doesn't work.

Comment: Remove android:fillVierport ="true". You need to give minHeight to SwipeRefreshLayout as it is not possible to scroll both webview and coordinatorlayout by just scrolling webview.You can scroll webview but not its parent without mentioning some fixed height to it.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick. I added this in layout

```
<yourpackage.name.NestedWebView 
    android:id="@id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

& This in java

https://github.com/takahirom/webview-in-coordinatorlayout/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/takahirom/webview_in_coodinator_layout/NestedWebView.java